# Check to make sure a number has been picked in each box

Tags: c#

I just want to have a check to make sure the user picked a number in the 2x2. So if the user doesnt pick a number in one of the boxes then I want a messagebog to popup telling the user to fill in all boxes.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to type anything other than numbers in NumericUpDown. Did you mean checking for a particular number or range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look into validation events and controls
this should start you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xht7x2.aspx